# Adding/Injecting Client Certificate into XMLHttpRequest

Tags: react-native, ssl, nginx, xmlhttprequest

I'm using [XMLHttpRequest](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/Libraries/Network/XMLHttpRequest.js) to send a request to nginx server that authenticates with SSL client certificate.
Is there a way to add my client certificate to my request of `XMLHttpRequest` in react native app or handling TLS Handshake happened while the request?

**Note**: i verified SSL client certificate authentication by using `curl` request with my key and cert. However i don't know how `curl` embed the certificate and key to the request (headers and body or handling TLS handshake).

Comment: shouldn't be a JWT or Bearer token help you with that instead of all certificate thingy